# Why colour does not change after change colour in loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="clm class2"></div>
<div class="clm class3"></div>
<div class="clm class4"></div>
<div class="clm class3"></div>
<div class="clm class4"></div>
```

And I have the following css code:

```
.clm{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-color: black;
}

.class1{
    background: red;
}

.class2{
    background: green;
}

.class3{
    background: blue;
}

.class4{
    background: black;
}
```

When I clicked div block with class `class2`, I need change all div's with `class3` to `class4`

For example:

before: `<div class="clm class3"></div>`

after click: `<div class="clm class4"></div>`

I have the following js code (jQuery):

```
$(".class2").click(function(){
        $(".class3").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('class','clm class4');
        });
    });
```

This code work fine. The colour is changed. I have the following other js script (jQuery):

```
$(".class4").click(function(){
        $(this).attr('class','clm class1');
    });
```

If I clicked to div with `class4` before click div with `class2` the code work ok, but when I clicked to div with `class2` and I try to change colour click in div with `class4` it's does not work.

P.S. the html code changed correctly and I see right colour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for all class names that are added/removed dynamically.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("body").on('click','.class4',function(){
    $(this).attr('class','clm class1');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you bind the `$('.class4')` click handler, the elements to which you're dynamically adding the `.class4` classname to do not exist. You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as follows:

```
$('body').on('click', '.class4', function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'clm class1');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kwcncw22/)

As a post-script to the above, it's also worth noting that using [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) is apparently much faster than setting the `class` attribute using `attr()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use **event delegation** for dynamically created class in the DOM. Otherwise DOM didn't know whether the class is found or not. In these use event delegation it traverse once again from the root of the body and find the class is found or not and

**Note:**
Use `.addClass()` for added new classes instead of `.attr()`

```
$("body").on('click','.class4',function(){
    $(this).addClass('clm class1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i feel this could be used $('.class3').removeClass("class3").addClass('class4');